# Repeat Sidekiq in case of failure but from a point where the failure occured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, sidekiq

I have a  Sidekiq job which can fail. The job contains a few operations making requests to REST API. In case of failure Sidekiq will repeat the job and it's by default. However, I don't want it to repeat the job from the beginning, it should  repeat from that operation which has caused the failure and up to the point when the last operation has been successful. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box this is obviously impossible. Sidekiq does not parse your code and he knows barely nothing about *where* the error occurred. One should break the job into chain of small jobs, one running other.

```
class Job1
  def perform
    ...
    Job2.perform_async
  end
end

...
```

That way as, say, Job3 failed, it will be rescheduled and everything will behave exactly as you want.

Comment: should I have one job-class-worker for each operation? is it an idiomatic way to achieve my goal?

Comment: While it’s the _only_ way to achieve your goal, I believe you should not care about how much is it idiomatic :)